# Using cURL, (how) is it possible to execute a PHP command on a remote page and return it as a string variable?

Tags: php, curl, remote-access

What I want to do using cURL:

1. Login to my Wordpress site, execute my own PHP code and save it to a variable:

   **$code_to_execute_remotely = wp_create_nonce('my_form');**

   $ch = curl_init();
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'www.mywordpresssite.com');
   **curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SOMEMYSTERIOUSFUNCTION, $code_to_execute_remotely); 
   $resulting_variable = curl_exec($ch);**
2. Then use that variable in a 2nd cURL execution:

   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_MYSECONDFUNCTION, **$resulting_variable**);
   $second_ececution = curl_exec($ch);
   curl_close($ch);

I've used dummy code to simplify things of course. The other functionality (logging into the remote site, etc.) is no problem, just executing that code remotely and returning its results as a usable variable, that's all I need. Since I'm not terribly familiar w/ cURL, it's possible I'm attempting something beyond its bounds, in which case I'd be very thankful to know what alternative *could* achieve this.

Comment: No such option exists. Just pass your code to be executed as URL parameter, or as POST variable. It has nothing to do with curl, but how you want to handle it on your receiving wordpress blog. (Just presuming you want to execute it *on your own* blog.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the remote site use the php eval function:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php

Edit with full explanation:

On your local server:

```
$post_data['curl_function'] = 'print wp_create_nonce("my_form");'; 
$post_string = http_build_query($post_data); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'www.mywordpresssite.com/receiver.php');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_string); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$result = curl_exec($ch); //This will contain whatever receiver.php prints
```

On the remote server in receiver.php:

```
print eval($_POST['curl_function']);
```

Notes:

- This will only work if you can access the remote server www.mywordpresssite.com and upload the receiver.php
- This is very unsafe for the remote server if you don't sanitize the input and have a way to check so that only your local server can send this request.
- But then again if you can access the remote server why send code through cURl when you can just write the functionality directly in receiver.php?
- So the if you can't access the remote server then the answer would be; No, you can't run code through cURL on another server if you want access the remote server and upload files to it.

Comment: So that would look like this?  On my local cURL script: $post_data['curl_function'] = 'print wp_create_nonce("my_form");';  $post_string = http_build_query($post_data);  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_string);  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);...  Then later in the cURL script after the 1st execution: $variable = eval($_POST["curl_function"]);  Is that right?

Comment: It's right except for the eval needs to be on the server receiving the cURL request. I'll edit my answer to clear everything up for you.

Comment: Yes, I think I now understand everything you've posted and that clears things up considerably (mostly as to the limits of cURL & remote code execution).  Thanks so much for you help!